# Jquery/Javascript - Variables scope and behaviour in jquery ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax-request

I'm with an weird behaviour that I cannot understand. Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    dataType: ...,
       data: ...,
    success: function( data ) {
            ...

            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

                label_to_change = "some-" + i + "-item"

                        $.ajax({
                            url: ...,
                            dataType: ...,
                               data: ...,
                            success: function( data ) {

                                // Why I can't access the value in each loop, this will give me allways the last loop value
                                console.log(label_to_change)
                            }
                        }); 
            } 
    }
});
```

I need to access the var label_to_change in the second ajax request but instead of getting this:

```
some-0-item
some-1-item
some-2-item
```

I got this:

```
some-2-item
some-2-item
some-2-item
```

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards,

Comment: Your ajax call is asynchronous. It is called thrice and the first console.log will print the latest value of label_to_change. You might want to move the logging statement before the ajax call

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is that I need to use the variable in that place. I can pass the variable to get accessible by data variable for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because the `label_to_change` variable is a single instance, and the for loop is changing it 3 times before any of your ajax calls can complete. You could use an anonymous function (or whatever the correct term here is) and do something like this:

```
label_to_change = "some-" + i + "-item";

(function(newLabel){
    $.ajax({
       url: ...,
       dataType: ...,
       data: ...,
       success: function( data ) {
          console.log(newLabel)
       }
    }); 
})(label_to_change);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This solution gives me an error: [code]"-item" is not a function
(function(new_label_to_change){ [/code]

Comment: The problem was a missing ";". I've use always a ";" in JavaScript?

Comment: @André: yep, the missing semi-colon was an issue! Does it now work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** 
you should do this : (in the top of code)

```
var change_index=0;
```

in second ajax call :

```
complete : function(){
   change_index++;
}
```

here is :

```
   var change_index=0;
  var i=0;
    $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        dataType: ...,
           data: ...,
        success: function( data ) {
                ...

               while( i<data.length) {

                    label_to_change = "some-" + change_index + "-item"

                            $.ajax({
                                url: ...,
                                dataType: ...,
                                   data: ...,
                                success: function( data ) {


                                    console.log(label_to_change)
                                }
                complete:function(){
                                    change_index ++;
                 i++;
                }
                            }); 
                } 
        }
    });
```

because the ajax finishing time is related to the server page execution and **for statement** will execute much faster than server statements . so it will set the  **label_to_change** to 2 and maybe the ajax call has not finished yet. so you should increase the **label_to_change**  in complete event function of ajax not in forloop body.

Comment: I think the problem with this is that you will be assuming that each ajax call will finish in the correct order. The OP example doesn't make it clear, but if the `i` value or `label_to_change` value is used elsewhere, like one of the ajax params, then this could be a problem

Comment: exactly opposite of your assumption .each ajax call won't finish in the correct order , so don't use iterator for this case , define a global variable which will be increased just time when a ajax call is finished.by using global variables you can make copy of all vars everywhere.

Comment: I didn't make an assumption, I suggested that you had made the assumption. Your updated code doesn't fix anything, you will still get the same problem, except this time it will always log "some-0-item"

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ajax call is reaching success after the for loop has completed. Therefore, the value it is using is only the most recent.

Declaring the label_to_change variable within the success function should work. Try this:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    //EDIT: added
    var iCurrent = i;

    $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        dataType: ...,
        data: ...,
        success: function( data ) {
            //placing the declaration inside this function will make the i value
            // be specific to this ajax call

            label_to_change = "some-" + iCurrent + "-item";

            console.log(label_to_change)
        }
    }); 
 }
```

Comment: and would this not have the same issue with `i` being set to the latest value by the time the ajax completes?

Comment: I have not had a chance to test this on my own, but it should not. Since the function is being declared with its OWN current value of i, the other iterations should have no effect on it. Variables declared in jQuery objects are local.

Comment: Yes, you may be right, it's not so easy to test these ajax problems so I cannot check

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But the solution is not working. The values is undefined.

Comment: Try it using the proxy variable iCurrent. I have had many problems with variable scope in jQuery.